# tmux status line and current path format

Tags: tmux

[Tmux](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1?query=tmux&sec=1) has an option to have the `#{pane_current_path}` as a name for the current pane in the status line. This is great but has two short falls for me:

1. `$HOME` is not displayed as `~`.
2. I only really need the last directory name, not the full path from `/`. So, for example `/home/ook/thingy/src` would only be displayed as either `src` or `~/t/src`.

Is there a [Tmux](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1?query=tmux&sec=1) command that does this?

Bonus points if it works with [powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline) as well.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using something similar to what you want:

```
setw -g window-status-format "#[underscore]#{?#{==:#{window_panes},1},,+}#[bold]#W#[nobold]:#{=|-24|…;s|$HOME|~|:pane_current_path}"
```

Stripping that down a bit to focus on the `pane_current_path` mangling:

```
"#{=|-24|…;s|$HOME|~|:pane_current_path}"
```

That replaces the home dir with `~` and removes all but the right-most 24 chars. Done this way, though, I note that the leading `~` is removed for long paths.

For just the leaf of the path:

```
"#{s|$HOME|~|;s|.*/||:pane_current_path}"
```

That time I put the `~` replacement first, so that when you're at home it displays `~` rather than `<username>`.

So to get closer to your `~/t/src` example:

```
"#{s|$HOME|~|;s|/.*/|/…/|:pane_current_path}"
```

will render as `~/…/src`. You should be able to use a modified pattern and a a backref, maybe combined with the `#{=` truncator, to get closer, but I'm not sure about getting all that right.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find something similar recently, in my case, for setting the window information (for the Tmux command `choose-window`) to something more informative than the default.

In the man page, the relevant information seems to be in the [FORMATS](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1?query=tmux&sec=1#x464f524d415453) section, which is also used by the `status-{left,right}` commands:

> FORMATS
>
> Certain commands accept the -F flag with a format argument. This is a
>   string which controls the output format of the command. Replacement
>   variables are enclosed in ‘#{’ and ‘}’, for example ‘#{session_name}’.
>   The possible variables are listed in the table below, or the name of a
>   tmux option may be used for an option's value. Some variables have a
>   shorter alias such as ‘#S’, and ‘##’ is replaced by a single ‘#’.
>
> Conditionals are available by prefixing with ‘?’ and separating two
>   alternatives with a comma; if the specified variable exists and is not
>   zero, the first alternative is chosen, otherwise the second is used.
>   For example ‘#{?session_attached,attached,not attached}’ will include
>   the string ‘attached’ if the session is attached and the string ‘not
>   attached’ if it is unattached, or ‘#{?automatic-rename,yes,no}’ will
>   include ‘yes’ if automatic-rename is enabled, or ‘no’ if not.
>
> A limit may be placed on the length of the resultant string by prefixing it by an ‘=’, a number and a colon. Positive numbers count from the start of
>   the string and negative from the end, so ‘#{=5:pane_title}’ will
>   include at most the first 5 characters of the pane title, or
>   ‘#{=-5:pane_title}’ the last 5 characters. Prefixing a time variable
>   with ‘t:’ will convert it to a string, so if ‘#{window_activity}’
>   gives ‘1445765102’, ‘#{t:window_activity}’ gives ‘Sun Oct 25 09:25:02
>   2015’. The ‘b:’ and ‘d:’ prefixes are basename(3) and dirname(3) of
>   the variable respectively. A prefix of the form ‘s/foo/bar/:’ will
>   substitute ‘foo’ with ‘bar’ throughout.
>
> In addition, the first line of
>   a shell command's output may be inserted using ‘#()’. For example,
>   ‘#(uptime)’ will insert the system's uptime. When constructing
>   formats, tmux does not wait for ‘#()’ commands to finish; instead, the
>   previous result from running the same command is used, or a
>   placeholder if the command has not been run before. Commands are
>   executed with the tmux global environment set (see the ENVIRONMENT
>   section).

After some attempts, I can't seem to make the built-in `sed`-like method work with the `#{pane_current_path}` directory name. Since you can also use any shell command or environmental variables, though, you can simply use some variation of

`set status-left "#(basename ${PWD})"`

I don't know about Powerline compatibility, since at the moment I'm not using it.

Comment: I cannot get this to work...  Ah well, thank you nonetheless.